# Set margin and font before printing java?

Tags: java, printing

I want to create printing service in java from txt document in which i need to set margin and font before printing.

Method `printjob` works fine but resulting margin and font is not as expected.How to resolve my problem ?
 :( 
Sorry for my english :) Thank's before and for help

```
public void test() {
            FileInputStream inStream = null;
            try {
                inStream = new FileInputStream("Test.txt");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ffne) {
            }
            if (inStream == null) {
                return;
            }

            DocFlavor psInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
            Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(inStream, psInFormat, null);

            String printerName = "\\\\\\192.168.1.8\\EPSON L210 Series";

            PrintServiceAttributeSet printServiceAttributeSet = new HashPrintServiceAttributeSet();
            printServiceAttributeSet.add(new PrinterName(printerName, null));
            PrintService[] printServices = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();
            System.out.println("printServices = " + printServices.length);
            System.out.println("printServices = " + printServices);
            PrintService defaultPrintservice = printServices[0];
            for (PrintService printService1 : printServices) {
                System.out.println("printService1 = " + printService1.getName());
                if (printService1.getName().contains("192.168.1.8")) {
                    defaultPrintservice = printService1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            PrinterJob printerjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
            try {
                printerjob.setPrintService(defaultPrintservice);
            } catch (PrinterException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PrintingService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }


            DocPrintJob job = defaultPrintservice.createPrintJob();

            try {
                PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
                SimpleDoc simpleDoc = new SimpleDoc(inStream, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE, null);
                aset.add(new Copies(1));
                aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
                aset.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);
                aset.add(Sides.DUPLEX);
                aset.add(JobSheets.NONE);
                //aset.add((Attribute) DocFlavor.READER.TEXT_PLAIN);
                job.print(simpleDoc, aset);
            } catch (PrintException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PrintingService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: hi...welcome to SO, to get answers, you have to tell us where your are stucked and what have you tried so far...please show us some code or error which u have coded or got!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor this link my code [link](http://pastebin.com/Xb9e44kT)

Comment: please add the relevant part of code in your question..... my office proxy wont allow access to pastebin!! ;)

Comment: @NoobEditor i just updated my code please check :D

Comment: sorry i am not able to find the solution to ur prob...while some1 else is not posting a solution, please check http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.awt.print/PrinterJobdefaultPage.htm